# Function is apparently mocked and called when inspected at a break point, but `assert_called_with` fails

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, with-statement, smtplib

I'm trying to write a test for `send_email`:

```
def send_email(email_info):
    user_name, user_email, message = email_info
    recipient = f'{user_name} <{user_email}>'
    message = format_email(message, UNAME, recipient)
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP(SERVER, PORT) as server:
        server.starttls(context=context)
        server.login(UNAME, PASSWORD)
        server.send_message(message)
    return
```

`send_email` is in my project subdirectory `<project_name>/base/tasks`.

Here's my attempt at a test:

```
import mock
from pytest_mock import mocker

class TestEmailFunctions:
    @mock.patch('<project_name>.base.tasks.smtplib')
    def test_send_email(self, mock_smtp, mocker):
        server = mocker.MagicMock()
        server.starttls = mocker.MagicMock()
        server.login = mocker.MagicMock()
        server.send_message = mocker.MagicMock()
        mock_smtp.SMTP = mocker.MagicMock()
        mock_smtp.SMTP.return_value = server
        msg = {'subject': "Hi, Elmo!", 'body':"It's Grover!"}
        send_email(('Elmo', 'elmo@sesamestreet.org', msg))
        mock_smtp.SMTP.assert_called_once()
        server.login.assert_called_once()
        assert server.login.call_args[0] == 'Elmo'
        server.send_message.assert_called_once()
        assert server.send_message.call_args == 'Hi, Elmo!'
```

`mock_smtp.SMTP.assert_called_once()` passes, so I know mocking is handled correctly up through the SMTP method.  But `server.login.assert_called_once()` fails: `AssertionError: Expected 'login' to have been called once. Called 0 times.`

I've inserted a breakpoint a bunch of different places, but skipping to the most dispositive one -- I put one in the function itself, not the test, right after I called `server.login()` with its arguments:

```
-> server.send_message(message)
(Pdb) server
<MagicMock name='mock().__enter__()' id='4581656560'>
(Pdb) server.login
<MagicMock name='mock().__enter__().login' id='4581885096'>
(Pdb) server.login.mock_calls
[call('<our email>', '<email password>')]
```

It really seems like I set up the mocks correctly, so I'm at a loss as to why `mock_smtp.SMTP.assert_called_once()` passes but `server.login.assert_called_once()` fails.  Maybe it's something about the `with` statement?  I'd appreciate it if anyone could provide an explanation and some advice about the proper way to test this function.

Comment: You created the `mock_smtp` for smtplib, and `server` for method from `stmplib.SMTP.server`, but you associated the object `SMTP` wtih another mock. Try to use the `mock_smtp.SMTP.startttls` as a new mock. Same for login and `send_message`.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi I'm struggling to understand.  Sorry -- this is probably my failure/confusion.  But I don't think `mock_smtp.SMTP.startttls` or this `stmplib.SMTP.server` are existing objects I can mock.  Rather, `mock_smtp.SMTP(<args>) returns `server` -- `server` isn't a method.  If I mocked `mock_smtp.SMTP.starttls` I think it would have no effect.  Not totally understanding what you meant, I did try, and I added `mock_smtp.SMTP.starttls = mocker.MagicMock()` etc. and tried `mock_smtp.SMTP.login.assert_called_once()`, but this fails as I would have expected, with `called 0 times`.